# Can Brownian particle itself theoretically exhibit thermal motion?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory, brownian-motion

The reason that we observe a Brownian Motion of a particle is being commonly explained by collisions of molecules of the surrounding fluid (liquid, gas) that the Brownian particle is suspended in. Generally, we omit the Brownian motion's own translational movement.

Theoretically, **what would happen when the particle has no surrounding molecules?** I believe there should still be some "thermal force" acting on the particle itself (the same way it acts on small molecules of gas/liquid) but it would not be observable because the force is too small for particle of that mass. However, I'm having difficulties on how to prove or explain it.

A) Is it possible to use the kinetic theory of gases to explain that the own thermal motion of the micrometer particle would be negligible?

B) Or can it be explained that the particle itself has some internal energy U but its molecules' random thermal motion is somehow keeping it in place?

I understand that when there are no surrounding molecules we should be talking about quantum vacuum as there will essentially be no temperature and we'd have to consider quantum fluctuations. As described here for example: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1018846501958. But this question is focused only on the thermal motion theory.

Thanks for any inputs and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

An isolated particle will simply move according to quantum mechanics. It won't be Brownian motion. There is no reason to expect Brownin motion when the context that produces Brownian motion is absent.

In the usual demonstration of Brownian motion the particle moving is something such as a smoke particle large enough to be visible in a visible light microscope, some microns in diameter. Such particles are large numbers of atoms. This means that the quantum behavior of a single isolated smoke particle is averaged out quite strongly and it will be following the classical path.

Therefore, an isolated Brownian motion particle is likely to be observed to simply move in a straight line for the most part. Unless it is very small, or unless there is some unusual circumstance that allows the quantum behavior to be emphasized.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, BillOnne. I understand that without the surrounding molecules it is simply not a Brownian motion, but let me rephrase the question a bit. When a micron particle is suspended in a liquid its motion is the result of the collisions. Does the force that acts on the molecules of the liquid affects also the micron particle? Even though that the effect is negligible?

Comment: @kubikss0n: the force that acts on the molecules of the liquid is exerted by the other molecules of the liquid and by the larger particle(s) suspended in the liquid.  At the microscopic level, all of these "thermal forces" are effectively billiard-ball collisions describable by Newtonian physics (or by quantum mechanics if you're in a situation where that's applicable.)